# (U)Mounting through "exec" with "sudo". The user is a "sudoer" with NOPASSWD

Tags: php, linux, root, sudo, archlinux

I've already taken a look at both of these:

- [PHP: mount USB device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147245/php-mount-usb-device)
- [Error on mount through php "exec"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455841/error-on-mount-through-php-exec)

But, my problem appears to be different.

---

I have built an extensive library that's used to call Linux CLI tools. It's built around [`proc_open`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php), it's family and [`POSIX`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.posix.php).

I'm using it to successfully execute *all* (until I hit this `mount`/`umount` bug) CLI tools.

Now, I'm building a RAID setup routine, that involves `partprobe`, `parted` - **rm**, **mklabel**, **mkpart**, `mdadm` - **stop**, **zero-superblock**, **create**, `dd`, `mkfs` and ultimately `mount`/`umount`.

There are actually two graceful routines, one for assembling the RAID, the other one for disassembly.

As the title says, the problem relies in `mount` and `umount`. The other tools and their commands listed above execute successfully.

#### Environment

Arch Linux - Linux stone 3.11.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Oct 18 23:22:36 CEST 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

The Arch is running with `systemd` - might be that is somehow affecting the mounting.

An Apache web server (latest), that runs mod_php (latest). Apache is run as `http:http`.

`http` is in `wheel` group, and `wheels` are sudoers - `%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`.
<sub>Please, don't start the *`webserver` being given a full root capabilities* discussion - the unit is a NAS, it's running a custom WebOS, and it's meant for intranet only. Even if there are hacking attempts - those will, most probably, break the whole system and that's not healthy for the customer. The NAS is a storage for [Mobotix IP cameras](http://www.mobotix.com/eng_US/), it runs a load of dependent services and the units are already deployed in over 30 objects with no issues. In short, the `webserver` is not serving *a web*, but an OS.</sub>

Before writing, I added, for a quick test, `http` explicitly to sudoers - `http ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` - didn't work.

#### Problem

The last command run in the RAID assembly process is `mount /dev/md/stone\:supershare /mnt/supershare`, which returns with an exit code of `0`.

Performing a subsequent mount results in:

```
mount: /dev/md127 is already mounted or /mnt/supershare busy
/dev/md127 is already mounted on /mnt/supershare
```

with an exit code of `32`. So, the array is mounted somewhere.

Performing an `umount /dev/md/stone\:supershare` afterwards the above `mount`, returns with an exit code of `0`. Performing an subsequent `umount` results in:

```
umount: /dev/md/stone:supershare: not mounted
```

<sub>The commands above are auto-run with sudo.</sub>

So, it's mounted successfully and unmounted sucessfully, but... I'm logged in as `root` on TTY0, running `lsblk` after having performed the `mount` operation, yet, I do not see the `mountpoint`:

```
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda         8:0    0  55.9G  0 disk
├─sda1      8:1    0     1M  0 part
├─sda2      8:2    0     1G  0 part  [SWAP]
├─sda3      8:3    0    12G  0 part  /
└─sda4      8:4    0  16.6G  0 part  /home
sdb         8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sdb1      8:17   0   899M  0 part
  └─md127   9:127  0   1.8G  0 raid0
sdc         8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sdc1      8:33   0   899M  0 part
  └─md127   9:127  0   1.8G  0 raid0
```

Attempting the same `mount` command from TTY0 mounts it successfully (lsblk displays after).

---

If I `mount` it with my CLI tool, then run `mount -l` and `lsblk` also with the CLI tool, the mountpoint is visible.

Running immediately both commands from TTY0 as root, do not display the mountpoint.

---

Rebooting, to reset all mounts (not automounted), then, mounting from TTY0 and running `lsblk` from TTY0 displays the mountpoint.

Then, running `lsblk` with CLI tool, displays the mountpoint.

Then, running `umount` with CLI tool, exit code `0` - unmounted.

Running `lsblk` with CLI tool again, does not display the mountpoint.

Running `lsblk` from TTY0, still does display the mountpoint.

---

It appears that when the `mount`/`umount` is run with my CLI tool, it executes the commands privately for the `sudo` session runner.

`umount`ing after TTY0 has mounted, does unmount it, but again - privately.

---

Logging in from TTY0 as `http` and running `lsblk` after having mounted the RAID from CLI tool, the mountpoint is not displayed. *This kind of negates the "executes privately for the `sudo` session runner".*

---

I've also found a material in [IBM's](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds3/mount.htm):

> The **mount command uses the real user ID, not the effective user ID**, to determine if the user has appropriate access. System group members can issue device mounts, provided they have write access to the mount point and those mounts specified in the /etc/file systems file. **Users with root user authority can issue any mount command**.

---

I hope I've explained good enough and not too confusing, I also hope that you guys will be able to help me catch the issue here.

---

#### Update (2013-10-28)

I attempted a test with the CLI tool outside web context, a simple PHP file, that'd I exec with `root` and a custom user.

In both scenarios, the mounting and unmounting was successful. So, it must be something with Apache executing the commands, though, I don't understand why do other commands work.

#### Question

What is causing the issue, and how do I overcome it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, the [hassle has been resolved](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98191/23212).

It was the Apache's corresponding `systemd` service, that had [`PrivateTmp=true`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#PrivateTmp=) directive. Apparently, the directive executes the process with a new file system namespace.

---

This question, while attempting to debug and fix the issue spawned a numerous other posts around the internet.

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97897/sudo-mount-from-webserver-apache-by-mod-php-result-not-visible-by-root
2. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=172072
3. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98182/a-process-run-as-root-when-performing-mount-is-mounting-for-self-how-to-ma/98191#98191

Each derived from stuff I've learn in the process.

I started with getting deeper information about `mount` working on `EUID`. Soon, I found out that my simple `sudo` call is actually not executing with `EUID 0`. That led me to multiple queries on how to do so, that in return spawned command syntax like `sudo -i 'su' -c 'mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/firstone'` and other derivatives.

Having no success with the solution, I looked further.

I started to think of trying to add the entry to `/etc/fstab`, that led me to loads of permission issues. Also, `sudo` and my CLI tool proved to be incomplete for the task. Lets bring the big weapons - lets compile Apache with `-DBIG_SECURITY_HOLE`, also known as, give Apache the possibility to be run as `root`.

Lets append entry to the `tab`, lets attempt to mount... and... fail!

After numerous tests, queries and what not, I stumbled upon `per process mount` that led me [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html#NOTES) and opened the dimension of `namespaces` to me.

Okay, that explains everything - checking `/proc/<pid>/mounts` validates it, now, lets gnaw deeper and see how to overcome it.

Again, after numerous attempts and no success, I started posting questions based around my fresh knowledge of namespaces. Narrowing the questions down and becoming more technical (at least I think I did), that eventually led to a user hiciu who [pointed me](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1343315#p1343315) into `systemd` direction, specifically, Apaches service - [`PrivateTmp`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#PrivateTmp=).

Voila! ...apparently `systemd` can enforce new namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same strange behavior of apache and spent more than 3 days without any working solution. Then luckyly I found this post and as you described PrivateTmp caused the issue. In my case, I tried to mount a drive from php:

```
<?php
...
exec("sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/drive", $output, $ret);
...
?>
```

When I ran above code from web browser, exec function return 0 (success) and I was even abble to list thru mapped drive within the code:

```
exec("ls /mnt/drive", $o, $r);
foreach ($o as $line){
  echo $line.'<BR>';
}
```

But when I tried search for mapped drive from cli, I cannot see it. I tried everything, include change permissions, change php.ini etc. Nothing help. Until now, changing

```
PrivateTmp=false
```

in

```
/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service
```

does the trick. Thank you very much for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

It was searching for this and is looks like this behavior is implemented and detectable from php via chroot:

```
 system('ischroot;echo $?');
```

gives 0 with the setting PrivateTmp=true (saying 'you are in a chroot') and 1 with PrivateTemp=false.