# Remount root file-system via PHP and apache2 doesn't work before execute mount via shell

Tags: php, apache2, mount

I created a read-only system on Raspberry Pi with Debian Buster for an embedded application.
The apache2 server is running on it with a configuration web page for the application that I need.
I need to remount the filesystem in read-write mode for editing a system file and I added a toolbox button on a php page that call a shell function.

This is the code for particular button:

```
<p><label>Remount Read-Write</label>
<button type="submit" name="rw">Remount</button>
</p>
<p><label>Remount Read-Only</label>
<button type="submit" name="ro">Remount</button>
</p>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['rw'])){
        $cmd='sudo /home/pi/mount.sh --rw';
        shell_exec($cmd);
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['ro'])){
        $cmd='sudo /home/pi/mount.sh --ro';
        shell_exec($cmd);
    }
?>
```

Inside the shell script, there is a line of code for mounting the root path in rw mode with the option '--rw',
in particular the command is:

```
/bin/mount -o remount,rw /
```

and the same with with '--ro' but with ro option.

I also added a suoders file in /etc/sudoers.d with this line:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/pi/mount.sh
```

The problem is that the command is executed without errors but the file system is not remounted.
If I do the command via shell like this:

```
p@localhost# sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

the php shell_exec starts to work and I can mount and remount by php page.

I cannot understand why the php page starts to work only after I do the remount via shell.

**Edit**

This is the script that is called:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Remount filesystem
# Options:
#           --rw:       remount read-write filesystem
#           --ro:       remount read-only filesystem

if [ "$#" == 1 ]; then
  if [ $1 == "--rw" ]; then
    sudo /bin/mount -o remount,rw /
    echo -e "Filesystem remounted in read-write mode"
  elif [ $1 == "--ro" ]; then
    sudo /bin/mount -o remount,ro /
    echo -e "Filesystem remounted in read-only mode"
  elif [ $1 == "--help" ] || [ $1 == "-h" ]; then
    echo -e "Remount Filesystem tool"
    echo "use remount.sh [OPTION]"
    echo ""
    echo -e "--rw         \tremount read-write filesystem"
    echo -e "--ro         \tremount read-only Filesystem"
    echo -e "--help (-h)  \tprint help"
  else
    echo "use -h or --help to see options"
  fi
else
    echo "use -h or --help to see options"
fi
```

**SOLVED**

I found the solution for the issue.

The main problem was due to a systemcl option on apache2.service.
By default the service have `PrivateTemp=true` option.
Changed in `PrivateTemp=false` solved the problem.

As I understood, `PrivateTemp` is set to `true` for creating a file system namespace that is not shared. By default apache2 create a separated namespace for security acces to temporary files.

Here a couple of links that I looked at for solving the problem:

[(U)Mounting through "exec" with "sudo". The user is a "sudoer" with NOPASSWD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598201/umounting-through-exec-with-sudo-the-user-is-a-sudoer-with-nopasswd)

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#PrivateTmp=

Comment: Please, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532304/execute-root-commands-via-php to see if this solves your problem.

Comment: I tried the wrapper but same result. The execution via web page does not remount before I use the shell with manually remount. After that, the buttons on php start to work and remount filesystem throug the wrapper.

Comment: Can you edit your question in order to show the relevant lines of the shell script to remount the root filesystem?

Comment: I edited the post with the entire bash script that i call via PHP

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the assignments of your PHP code above. Assignments in PHP are not like in BASH.

Change `cmd=` into `$cmd=` on two places.

If you don't do so, you will pass an empty string to the function `shell_exec`.

So try:

```html
<p><label>Remount Read-Write</label>
<button type="submit" name="rw">Remount</button>
</p>
<p><label>Remount Read-Only</label>
<button type="submit" name="ro">Remount</button>
</p>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['rw'])){
        $cmd='sudo /home/pi/mount.sh --rw';
        shell_exec($cmd);
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['ro'])){
        $cmd='sudo /home/pi/mount.sh --ro';
        shell_exec($cmd);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Sorry for mistake, in my code is all ok with $cmd. I did an error by typing in the comment here. 
The php page is executed with no errors, remount via buttons work only after I write on shell # sudo mount -o remount,rw /
Than buttons start to execute remounts. 
Seem that there is something that is trigged via shell command, but i don't know.

Comment: Do you know how often you need to trigger this behaviour again with the shell? After each reboot?

Comment: Only one time, Pierre after each reboot.

Comment: Is it possible that apache2 is running in an environment isolated by chroot? Could it be that remounting the system from the shell removes this protection? I am puzzled...

Comment: Thanks to your last comment, Pierre, I resolved the issue. apache2 is not running on a chrootted environment but this input helped me to find the solution. It was systemctl problem, that apache2 service create new not shared file system namespace. I wrote the solution on original post. Thankyou for your help.